# Laravel: Error getting response from a route in an Artisan Command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

So basically I was trying to fetch the output of a route on my application from a custom artisan command I created. I created the Request and dispatched it with the Router within the handle function and for testing, simply output the response to the console.

When I run the command from the console, I am always getting an error saying "Class web does not exist", where I believe 'web' is the middleware.

This is the first time I am trying to do this and I am stuck. I will really appreciate if you could check my code and help me figure out the cause of this error.

Here is my command:

```
<?php

namespace APP\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCmd extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'testcmd';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    protected $request;
    protected $router;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $request = Request::create('test-route', 'GET');

        $this->info($this->router->dispatch($request));
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 738: Class web does not exist
```

(This is just the error, the output is actually the default laravel error template that is displayed on the console)

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

To add more clarity to my question I wanted to describe my goal with this code. I want to run an artisan command from the command line that would fetch the response of a route in my application and return it. These routes are simply API end points. Please let me know if more details are required

Comment: Since you don't have any usage of the word *web* in this command, you probably have an error somewhere else in your code. See if you get this error if you run `php artisan route:list` for example. You could also make a full search of your project to see where you're using the word *web*.

Comment: @TheFallen Thanks for your comment. Actually the error is the response that I get when I dispatch the route. So it is certainly the Middleware 'web' that is applied to the route. The issue is when normally you point your browser to a url to access the route, it works fine, but doesn't work via my custom command. I want my command to dispatch the route and return the response. And I tried `route:list` and it works correctly.

Comment: I see now, but I'm not sure why this error would ever happen. I assume that when you manually open this URL you don't get this error, so have you tried making the request with curl instead of the Laravel request object?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function handle()
{
    $request = Request::create('test-route', 'GET');

    $kernel = app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $this->info($response->getOriginalContent());

}
```